# Understanding Regular Expression look ahead (?! | ?=)

Tags: regex

Can you please help understand why with this text:

> @Hello No tuve chance @World para ver felipe@email.com
>   @Hello No tuve chance @World:

this expression `/@World(?!:)/` works as expected but this one fails `/@(\w+)(?!:)/`? (at least it does not match the expected values=> `@ word excluding :`)

I thought this `/@World/` could be also converted into something like this `/@w+/` but it does not seem to be the case with look ahead. Can you please help me understand the differences?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to escape `@`, it has no special meaning in regexp.

Comment: javascript but I tried different options here http://regex101.com/r/mS7oD3#pcre all with same results

Comment: The second regexp matches `@Hello`

Comment: thanks Barmar I updated the scape character.. regarding matching @hello it is desired part of reasons of the regular expression in my current situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GREP is by default *greedy*: using `+` it matches as much as possible, while still returning a valid match.

Your `\@(\w+)(?!:)` fails because for "@World:" it returns "@Worl". It fits your expression: word characters and then not a ":" -- the next character is a `d`.

Use this instead:

```
\@(\w+)\b(?!:)
```

That way, it has no choice *but* to test the entire string "@World", followed by not-a-word character -- and if it does, it must not be a colon.

Comment: You're missing the `+`.

Comment: Thanks this is nice... btw missed a + sign in your last expression other than that this explains it

Comment: Thx for the heads-up. Typing on an iPad is hard :)